# Dojo / Dijit BorderContainer in Dijit.Dialog

Tags: layout, dojo

I am trying to programatically create layout like this:[image]

I am using dojo 1.7 and there is probably a problem with layout initialization. 
This is my [attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaboshi/Za8Lw/1/).

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let the `BorderContainer` set the size of the `Dialog` (not the dialog itself): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/Za8Lw/11/).

```
var layout = new BorderContainer({
    design: "headline",
    style: "width: 400px; height: 400px;"
});
```

Alternatively, in your case, you can avoid using `dijit.layout` at all. Place the content of a dialog inside `<div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea"></div>` and buttons into `<div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar"></div>` and you will get:

[image]

Source: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/test_Dialog.html

Comment: Thank you for very helpfull answer. Both solutions are great! And also, thank you for source.